# How can I add a classpath entry to the Kotlin Interactive Shell?

Tags: shell, kotlin, classpath

How can I add a classpath entry to the [Kotlin Interactive Shell](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-interactive-shell)?

Comment: Do you mean the current classpath entry? (i.e. when you run `:classpath` inside `ki` you get the current script compilation classpath, is that what you're trying to modify?)

Comment: Yes, the current classpath entry.